# How to implement pause in Windows Store Application?

Tags: multithreading, windows-store-apps, async-await, thread-sleep

I'm creating a Slideshow app for Windows Store. I want 3 seconds pause between pics.

```
await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
```

Above code works fine for me but thread gets completed after about 30 seconds with 0 code. 
I know 0 means success but the above code is inside a forever loop (If pic index reached at the end then reset the index from starting, just like Windows Photoviewer)

How can I achieve desired functionality?

Update: here is code

```
private async void slideshow()
    {
        while (current_pic_index < fileList.Count)
        {

            if (current_pic_index < 0)
            {   
                current_pic_index = fileList.Count - 1;
            }

            IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await fileList[current_pic_index].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
            bi3.SetSource(fileStream);
            ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();

            Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
            ContentRoot.Children.Add(DynamicGrid);

            DynamicGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
            DynamicGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
            DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
            DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
            DynamicGrid.Background = myBrush;

            DynamicGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
            DynamicGrid.ManipulationStarted += test_grid_ManipulationStarted;
            DynamicGrid.ManipulationCompleted += test_grid_ManipulationCompleted;

            await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
            current_pic_index++;

            if(current_pic_index == fileList.Count)
            {
                current_pic_index = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you know why the thread runs to completion in 30 seconds even if the loop is infinite?

Comment: [`Task.Delay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh139096(v=vs.110).aspx) returns just a `Task`, not a `Task<int>`. It's unclear what you mean by "get completed ... with code 0". Could you clarify? Also, consider sharing the loop code as well.

Comment: @kennyzx No I can't understand. First I thought maybe it is because of some invalid index. But it is for 30 secs. Suppose if I add 5 pics then loop continue two times. But then I add 3 more pics then loop was running for 1 and half times means first round complete then break in middle of second round.

Comment: @c45207 I'm new in this field. I'm trying to learn from stackoverflow. I have s function named slideshow(). All  I want to pause everything for 3 seconds. Can you tell me how to do it?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with this line of code, you need to show the rest code- the slideshow(), and the while loop.

Comment: @kennyzx Code added to post.

Comment: looks like you are running out of memory because you keep adding a _new_ DynamicGrid to ContentRoot _every time_ you showing a slide. Check the task manager, does the memory consumption of the app steadily grow?

Comment: @kennyzx Thanks. Dynamic Grid was causing problem. 
At the end I got following msg 
'The thread 0xcfc has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xdc8 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xa88 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0xd20 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The thread 0x458 has exited with code 259 (0x103).
The program '[3576] App6.exe' has exited with code 0 (0x0).' 

Code 259 means thread is STILL_ACTIVE. It may cause any problem? Or just I should ignore it?

Comment: What is the calling code? You might want to read the articles in [my `async-await` curation](http://curah.microsoft.com/45553/asyncawait-general).

Answer (score 0):

You are putting a delay in the UI thread which is never a good idea. You should run this function in a new thread and call into the UI thread when needed:

```
    private void slideshow()
    {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (current_pic_index < fileList.Count)
            {

                if (current_pic_index < 0)
                {
                    current_pic_index = fileList.Count - 1;
                }

                IRandomAccessStream fileStream = await fileList[current_pic_index].OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                    BitmapImage bi3 = new BitmapImage();
                    bi3.SetSource(fileStream);
                    ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();

                    Grid DynamicGrid = new Grid();
                    ContentRoot.Children.Add(DynamicGrid);

                    DynamicGrid.Width = Window.Current.Bounds.Width;
                    DynamicGrid.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;
                    DynamicGrid.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                    DynamicGrid.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;
                    DynamicGrid.Background = myBrush;

                    DynamicGrid.ManipulationMode = ManipulationModes.TranslateX;
                    DynamicGrid.ManipulationStarted += test_grid_ManipulationStarted;
                    DynamicGrid.ManipulationCompleted += test_grid_ManipulationCompleted;
                });

                await System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3));
                current_pic_index++;

                if (current_pic_index == fileList.Count)
                {
                    current_pic_index = 0;
                }
            }
        });
    }
```